# How to view local site on mobile?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7

I have a windows 7 laptop and a phone, both connected to my home wifi network. I have a local site running on my IIS7 windows laptop. If I type localhost, I can see the default page.

The problem is that now I want to view that page on my phone. How can I get to it?

I tried

localhost:81

I tried getting my public ip, then putting :81 after, and it didn't work.

Anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: A basic understanding of how the average consumer network works would be useful here. You ought to use the internal ip of the server. This is also ot here since no reasonable business would run a webserver on  a workstation os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First option:**

You need to use your local IP of the laptop to connect to the website on the your phone. IPs starting with 192.168.1.xx.

Use command prompt to get your IP. Type "ipconfig" and then look under IPv4 Address for your IP.

The laptop's firewall will need port 80 opened for incoming connections.

**Second option:**

Use [Adobe Inspect](https://creative.adobe.com/products/inspect). After installing the extension and other applications, you can mirror your browser window with any devices connected. So you could have a phone, tablet etc all reading from the same window. Any changes will be directly pushed to all connected devices.

The best part of this is that you don't have to mess with IIS or firewalls.